# How to archive the content of a folder recursively as artifacts on Jenkins?

Tags: recursion, jenkins, directory, artifacts

My jenkins job creates a temporary subfolder, say "mydir", within the workspace that I then want to archive using the postbuild step "Archive artifacts".

I'm using the following command:

```
mydir/**/*
```

It works well **but** the archive will always contains mydir as the root of the artifacts whereas I would like to have the **contents** of this folder only.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dir()` to archive the artifact from inside the desired directory:

```
    stage('Archive') {
        steps {
            dir('mydir') {
                archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**'
            }
        }
    }
```

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#dir-change-current-directory

Answer (score 2):

To archive your entire folder in jenkins.

In your case let us say. If you want to archive complete "mydir" folder

```
**/my_dir/**
```

That is one way. If you have other folders with the same name. Then you can provide proper parent directory as well.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in this cases is create a compressed file (tar or zip) of the directory I'm interested, and then artifact it instead artifact the whole directory. If your slave is running in linux you can do as follow:

```
tar -czvf name-of-archive.tar.gz /path/of/build/directory
```

Then artifact name-of-archive.tar.gz

Answer (score -1):

You can check the option "Flatten directories" on the plugin's settings

Comment: This comment applies to the `Copy Artifact` plugin that is not installed by default